# Flutter : Can't load specific data from API

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to load data from an API but it returns a null value. i've tried changing the url to a String but its the same

the API :

```
  "stores": [
  {
  "id": 290375,
  "url": "https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP1004-CUSA00419_00-GTAVDIGITALDOWNL", // this returns a null value 
  "store": {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "PlayStation Store",
  "slug": "playstation-store",
 "domain": "store.playstation.com",
 "games_count": 7377,
  "image_background": "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/328/3283617cb7d75d67257fc58339188742.jpg"
  }
  },
```

the Data Model :

```
class StoresModel {
final id;
final url;
final StoreModel store;

StoresModel(this.id,this.url,this.store);

StoresModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : id=json["id"]??"",
    url=json["url"]??"No Available Url",
    store=StoreModel.fromJson(json["store"]) ?? [];

}
```

Comment: Where you are parsing server response data to *StoresModel* ? Write that code pls

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use Future Function??
example:

```
   Future get getDatafx async {
  var url = 'your url';
  var response = await http.get(url);
  var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return responsebody;
}
```

then you can use Future builder

```
 return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
  future: getDatafx,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return Container(
            height: 100, width: 200, child: Text(snapshot.data[i]["timestamp"]));
      });
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
));
```

Comment: i'm using a future function and i'm getting all the data only the url i'm getting an empty variable .

Answer (score 0):

- Notice that your API response is a Map, and inside it there is a key called `"stores"`.
- When you access this key, you don't get your items directly back like `"id","url"..etc`, but you first get a List that wraps these elements, and this list contains another Map with your desired values `{"id", "url"..etc}`
- Your `['stores']` map is located at index[0].

So, in order to access these items and for this code to work, you should change the fromJson method to the following:

```
StoresModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : id=json["id"]??"",
    url=json["url"]??"No Available Url",
    store=StoreModel.fromJson(json["stores"][0]) ?? []; //<=This is the important step, add index[0] here.
  }
```

When you call it, you need to pass the correct path for your items.

This code should work:

```
var response = await http.get('yourUrl');
var decodedResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
StoresModel store = StoresModel.fromJson(decodedResponse);
```

This should solve your problem, please update on the outcome and results.

Comment: you might have misunderstood my problem. Everything works fine, but the data stored in the url returns an empty string .

Comment: That means that it being sent as a null a null value actually, when it arrives to your device. Yes, I misunderstood you first.

Comment: But if it's sent as a null value it'll return "no Available url" ?? and why it's sending a null value when it has data ?

Comment: if it's not returning "no Available url", then it's being sent as a String that is "null". Are you sure the other data is being parse fine?

Comment: yes i'm pretty sure and it appeared in my UI .